# .Except into a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, listview, except

I have two lists.

```
public IList<string> List1 { get; set; }
public IList<string> List2 { get; set; }
```

I am trying to compare two lists using `Except` and display the items in a `ListView`

I have this code to display in the `ListView`

```
var list = List1.Except(List2).ToString();
ListViewItem listView = new ListViewItem(list);
this.testListView.Items.Add(listView);
```

The output I get is `"System.Linq.Enumerable+<ExceptIterator>d__72'1[System.String]"`

I know I am doing something wrong but cannot figure out what is it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why doing ToString() after Except? You can do ToList().

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I tried it and in the second line of code I get an error saying cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to 'string'`

Comment: You want to add items of `list` variable in the ListView? Then you should loop thru the items of `list` and add them one by one to the ListView.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, I want to add them to a list. I am having trouble adding variable `list` to `new ListViewItem(list)` I get the above-said error when I use `.ToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this(assume you want to show one string in one row, though it's strange not use ListBox):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //add Columns, which you might have done in designer
        //this.testListView.Columns.Add...
        this.testListView.View = View.Details;
        var list = List1.Except(List2).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(list[i]);
            this.testListView.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes - you should always test for conditions like that and handle them.  eg. `if (list.Count ==0) return;`

Comment: @Dazzler updated, by the way, i don't know what your list will be like.

Comment: @LeiYang Thank you, that fixed the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. But I can only see 1 item in the list i.e., `list[0]`. Am I missing something? the listview contains only 1 column and around 300 entries of type `string`. And the list is not just one row, its multiple rows.

Comment: @LeiYang Thank you for the update and for the answer :)